# How to interact with location specific popups with selenium and python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to build a web scraper with selenium that pulls pricing and nutrition data from https://www.hannaford.com/home.jsp for a school project. The difficulty is that pricing data is store specific. To solve this I have used selenium to enter the users zip-code on the website. Afterwards, a pop up window opens with five of the nearest stores. The program needs to select a store from these locations.

I've copied the x-path of the button that selects the first store and set it to be clicked, but selenium still does not continue past the popup.

Here is my code:

```
hannaford = 
"https://www.hannaford.com/home.jsp"
    #opens website
    driver.get(hannaford)  

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="node01"]/a""").click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="pageContentWrapperInner"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/p[2]/a""").click()

    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="cityStateZipLayer"]""")
    inputElement.send_keys(zip)
    inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    #attempt to select store in popup
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="glo-store-results-layer-store-list"]/div[1]/span/form/a""").click()
```

and here is the html associated with the link I'm trying to click:

```
<span class="fr rightSide">
                    <form class="fr" action="/custserv/save_user_store.cmd" method="post" name="selectThisStoreForm"><input type="hidden" name="form_state" value="selectThisStoreForm"><input name="storeId" type="hidden" value="21185" autofillparam="ON"><a href="" onclick="javascript:saveUserStoreNoClose('21185');return false;" class="altLink">
                           <input class="shopNow" type="image" autofillparam="ON" src="/assets/hf/assets/images/buttons/btn_shopNow.gif" border="0" alt="Shop Now"></a>
                    </form></span>
```

How could I resolve this issue. Is it even possible to select dynamic elements like this in selenium?

Comment: The popup might not be loaded by the time you try to interact with it. Try adding a time.sleep(1) inbetween opening the popup and interacting with it.

Comment: What error do you get with your code? If it is `NoSuchElementException`, you should try using [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to wait for the element to load.

Comment: @Black_lotus What are the _Manual Steps_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: Thank you, @Brandon Lyons, using time.sleep(1) solved my issue!